# Sort array of objects based on values in another array that correspond to specific properties

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

Let's say retrieve an array of objects from a JSON API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 48,
        "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "id": 198,
        "name": "Dave"
    },
    {
        "id": 2301,
        "name": "Amy"
    },
    {
        "id": 990,
        "name": "Colette"
    }
]

// e.g. for ease of reproduction:

let dataObjects = [
    ["id": 48, "name": "Bob"], 
    ["id": 198, "name": "Dave"], 
    ["id": 2301, "name": "Amy"], 
    ["id": 990, "name": "Colette"]
]
```

On the client, I'd like to allow the user to re-order these objects. To save the order, I'll store a list of ids in an array:

```
let index: [Int] = [48, 990, 2103, 198]
```

How can I reorder the original array of data objects based on the order of ids in the sorting index?

```
dataObjects.sort({ 
    // magic happens here maybe?
}
```

So that in the end, I get:

```
print(dataObjects)
/* 
[
    ["id": 48, "name": "Bob"], 
    ["id": 990, "name": "Colette"], 
    ["id": 2301, "name": "Amy"], 
    ["id": 198, "name": "Dave"]
]
/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach A)** Parsing the data into a simple dictionary where the key for the dictionary is the id used to sort it:

```
func sort<Value>(a: [Int: Value], basedOn b: [Int]) -> [(Int, Value)] {
    return a.sort { x, y in
        b.indexOf(x.0) < b.indexOf(y.0)
    }
}

// ....
let a = [48:"Bob", 198:"Dave", 2301:"Amy", 990:"Colette"]
let b = [48, 198, 2301, 990]
sort(a, basedOn: b)
```

**Approach B)** With some custom `DataObject` type: (probably best way)

```
struct DataObject {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

    init(_ id: Int, _ name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

func sort(a: [DataObject], basedOn b: [Int]) -> [DataObject] {
    return a.sort { x, y in
        b.indexOf(x.id) < b.indexOf(y.id)
    }
}


let a = [DataObject(48, "Bob"), DataObject(198, "Dave"), DataObject(2301, "Amy"), DataObject(990, "Colette")]
let b = [48, 198, 2301, 990]

sort(a, basedOn: b)
/* [
     DataObject(id: 48, name: "Bob"), 
     DataObject(id: 990, name: "Colette"), 
     DataObject(id: 198, name: "Dave"), 
     DataObject(id: 2301, name: "Amy")
] */
```

**Approach C)** With the *raw* json values, it can be done in a less "clean" way:

```
func sort<Value>(a: [[String: Value]], basedOn b: [Int]) -> [[String: Value]] {
    return a.sort { x, y in
        let xId = x["id"] as! Int
        let yId = y["id"] as! Int
        return b.indexOf(xId) < b.indexOf(yId)
    }
}

let dataObjects = [
    ["id": 48, "name": "Bob"],
    ["id": 198, "name": "Dave"],
    ["id": 2301, "name": "Amy"],
    ["id": 990, "name": "Colette"]
]

let b = [48, 198, 2301, 990]

sort(dataObjects, basedOn: b)
```

Comment: Nope, not quite - my original array is an array of objects, not just key:value pairs. E.g. `a` looks like: `let a = [["id": 48, "name": "Bob"], ["id": 198, "name": "Dave"], ["id": 2301, "name": "Amy"], ["id": 990, "name": "Colette"]]`

Comment: if `a` looks like you commented I would suggest considering parsing the JSON array into an array of some custom type like in my answer, but even if you decide to stay with the *raw* data like you wrote it should be difficult, you would just call something like `x["id"].intValue`

Comment: Yeah, I was being lazy with my question - I'm doing what you're doing with a class instead of a struct, but same principle. Might as well remove the stuff above EDIT - your edit works perfectly!

Comment: @remus I left the first solution and added a third one to deal with the raw json data (the "lazy" approach) for the sake of community... glad it helped you

Answer (score 2):

You could benefit of the functional support that Swift has, and use the `map` function to iterate over the `index` array and get the corresponding object:

```
let sortedObjects = index.map{ id in
    dataObjects.filter{ $0["id"] as? Int == id }.first
}
```

This assumes that the `index` array is correctly computed before mapping the data objects.

---

#### Edit

Thanks to user3441734 for the `flatMap` suggestion. Here's a solution that makes use of it, basically it simply replaced `map` by `flatMap` in order to get rid of the possible `nil` values in the mapped array, and to convert the resulting array into an array of non-optionals.

```
let sortedObjects = index.flatMap{ id in
    dataObjects.filter{ $0["id"] as? Int == id }.first
}
```

If an empty `index` should result in the same order being kept, then we can simply test for that:

```
let sortedObjects = index.count > 0 ? index.flatMap{ id in
    dataObjects.filter{ $0["id"] as? Int == id }.first
} : dataObjects
```

Comment: nice! I suggest to use flatMap instead.

Comment: @user3441734 yes flatMap would be a viable alternative, as it would skip the `nil` values. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: One thing to factor in though is that I may not always have a valid index - it may be an empty array, it may have a value that was previously deleted? If you can write up a flatMap option that would take those into consideration, that'd be awesome

Comment: @remus if `index` is empty then what should be the sort oder for the data objects? Similar questions for values that don't have an corresponding value in `index`.

Comment: If index is empty, then the original order should be used. If there are extraneous index values in the sorting array that don't exist in the data, they should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep an array with the index you can sort by the object you want, let's says you have the following structure:

```
struct DataObject {
   var id: Int
   var name: String
}

var data = [DataObject]()
data.append(DataObject(id: 48, name: "Bob"))
data.append(DataObject(id: 198, name: "Dave"))
data.append(DataObject(id: 2301, name: "Amy"))
data.append(DataObject(id: 990, name: "Colette"))
```

The you can use the `sort` function to sort and return the result in other array or just the `sorted` function if you want to make it in-place

```
// ordered by id
var sortedData = data.sort { index.indexOf($0.id) < index.indexOf($1.id) }
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This doesn't preserve the original order like the OP is asking, it just sorts the objects by `id` from lowest to highest.

Comment: @JAL Yep sorry I code quickly and I missunderstand the question. Fixed thanks